# 'this' different behaviour in node and v8 chrome

Tags: javascript, this

I have:

```
function MyFunc() {
  this.myString = "wooooo";
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("printing this.myString", this.myString);
  }, 1000);
}

MyFunc();
```

If I run this inside node, I get the answer: `printing this.myString undefined` (btw `node --version gives v12.16.2`)

If I try this inside my console devtools in chrome browser, I get `printing this.myString wooooo` (btw I have chrome 89.0.4389.90)

Can anybody explain me why *this* is different in nodejs and js? Why has it different behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: This also happens in `node 15.5.1`. I don't think this is a V8 issue since both node and chrome use the v8 engine

Comment: Looks like this is because `this` inside the timeout handler refers to an instance of https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout . I couldn't find anything in the spec about what `this` is supposed to refer to in the timeout handler, so my guess is that the host environment decides. Browsers don't set a specific `this` value and Node seems to set the mentioned value.

Comment: I was actually trying this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gigtS_5KOqo&t=335s

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, both references to `this` should refer to the global object (assuming non-strict mode), since both references occur in "normal" functions.

That's what happens in the browser.

However, if you actually log the value of `this` you can see that it refers to an instance of [`Timeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) in Node:

```
Timeout {
  _idleTimeout: 1000,
  _idlePrev: null,
  _idleNext: null,
  _idleStart: 21,
  _onTimeout: [Function (anonymous)],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null,
  _destroyed: false,
  [Symbol(refed)]: true,
  [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 5,
  [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
}
```

It's very possible that it's not officially defined what `this` is supposed to refer to in the handler, so environments are free to do whatever they want in this regard.

Comment: It seems to be defined as `window` here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps. Although nobody says node should follow a DOM standard.

Comment: @georg: Ah and step 7.2 also says: *"Use method context proxy as the callback this value."*... I was looking for the wrong keywords. But yeah, I guess Node just provides a `setTimeout` implementation for convenience, not for following the DOM spec.